# Pull latest commit from a specific repository command

Tags: git, command-line, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket account with some repositories and I would like to know how to pull the latest commit (source code) through the command line. thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to read the [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that. Pull latest commit from master. These is the command line you need to give.

`git pull origin master`

And, checking out the specific commit,

`git checkout (commit-id)`

Comment: Thanks @Lethalprogrammer. Have any idea on how to compile it into apk using the command line ?